# How to delete and re-insert entities in linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, insert, submit

I am having troubles inserting entities in linq after deleting them (without submitting the changes).

```
List<AlergiesPerPersonBE> AlergiesPerPerson = AlergiesPerPersonToInsert;

RepositoryFactory.GetAlergiesPerPersonRepository().DeleteWhere(x => x.PersonId == id);
RepositoryFactory.GetAlergiesPerPersonRepository().Insert(AlergiesPerPerson);

DataContextFactory.SubmitChanges();
```

Both (delete and insert) don´t submit any changes. They just InsertAllOnSubmit and DeleteAllOnSumbit.

The code works fine the first time. All the details are inserted properly. The second time that I run the same code, all rows of the db are deleted. The third time, all works fine. It works, then it doesn't, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
...DeleteWhere(x => x.PersonId == id); 
DataContextFactory.SubmitChanges();

...Insert(AlergiesPerPerson);
DataContextFactory.SubmitChanges();
```

There's no reason that you have to submit changes only once per unit of work.  Note that this will still work with any transactions that you have.

Comment: I thought that when you do the SubmitChanges then all the work is done "at once". thats why I was doing just one. So you think that I should enclose the whole thing with TransacionScope?

Comment: @Marco When you call SubmitChanges then all the pending work is done, but you can do more after calling it.  You can wrap the work in a transaction scope if you think best; it's not difficult and can be beneficial.  If you don't need the transaction, though, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: So what if I want these changes to take effect together for performance reasons?  Won't the above code cause two round-trips to the database instead of one?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski When you call `SubmitChanges` you're telling the datacontext to perform any pending SQL queries; if you call it when there are multiple pending queries then they will 'take effect together'. It's not possible to write a query that inserts and deletes in a single statement! In this case the insert and delete queries will be sent as two queries within a single connection or context - just like writing two queries inline in SQL Management Studio. LINQ-to-SQL does have performance considerations but I don't think this is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to recreate the details again.
The context is currently tracking this item as being 'deleted' even if save changes hasn't yet been called.

Comment: i recreate the details object every time (other instances) but the content is the same. does linq execute the commands in order? i mean: first perform all delete operations and then all insert operations?

Answer (score 0):

There is dirty work around. Since you want to get rid of DataContext observer you will need to:

1. serialize object or graph to memory
   stream.
2. Then deserialize it back as new instance
3. change ID to 0
4. Attach new object to DataContext and submit
   changes.
5. Delete previous

You can move this to CloneHelper static class so you can use it for any type

Comment: the objects are new instances. everytime i access db y convert the linq object to another entity object. basically i copy and paste every property from one side to another. so, the object to insert is not the one referenced by the datacontext. and there is no ID, i changed to Details just to exemplify, but the real thing is like this: AlergiesPerPerson, where i have the personId and the alergyId.